# No Suitable Found for add String

Tags: java

Am trying to retrieve data I Chosen From mysql and filter table the Item I choose by getting value of chosen Item I created A list this list am trying to add on it the chosen Item but I fount an underlined error No Suitable Found for add String
this is my main.java contains code I use

```
    List<Menu> listItem = new ArrayList<Menu>();

    if (insertedNumberOfCovers) {
        Menu m = new Menu();
        m.getAllRows();
        while (orderNotFinished) {

            System.out.println("Please Choose Item From Menu List");

            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            itemChosen = input.nextLine();
            boolean insertedMenuItemId = db.goTodataBase.checkMenuItemInDB(itemChosen);
            if (insertedMenuItemId) {
                System.out.println("You Choose Item ID: " + itemChosen);

                listItem.add(m.getAllRows(itemChosen));
                System.out.print("Do you need to add more Items ? ");
                hasFinished = input.nextLine();
                orderNotFinished = hasFinished.equals("yes");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Item Chosen doen't exist");
            }

        }
```

and this is Menu.java that I retrieve data from
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package enitities;

import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Menu {

    private int Menu_Id;
    private String Name;
    private float Price;
    private String Type;
    private String Category;

    public int getMenu_Id() {
        return Menu_Id;
    }

    public void setMenu_Id(int Menu_Id) {
        this.Menu_Id = Menu_Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float Price) {
        this.Price = Price;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String Type) {
        this.Type = Type;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String Category) {
        this.Category = Category;
    }

    public void getAllRows() {
        db.goTodataBase.printData("menu");
    }

public Menu getAllRows(Menu itemChosen) {
    db.goTodataBase.printData("menu");
    return itemChosen;
}

    public String getValueByName(String itemChosen) {
        String strSelect = "select Menu_Id from menu"
                + "where name=" + Name;
        return itemChosen;
    }
}
```

and this method that am Using to Print Table Values

```
    public static void printData(String tableNameOrSelectStatement) {
        try {
            setConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            String strSelectPart = tableNameOrSelectStatement.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase();
            String strSelect;
            if ("select ".equals(strSelectPart)) {
                strSelect = tableNameOrSelectStatement;
            } else {
                strSelect = "select * from " + tableNameOrSelectStatement;
            }
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int c = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
                    if (i > 1) {
                        System.out.print(",  ");
                    }
                    String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
//                    System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                    System.out.print(columnValue + " ");

                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Tools.msgBox(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

the error in this line

```
                listItem.add(m.getAllRows(itemChosen));
```

Comment: What, on earth, are you trying to say, after all?

Comment: you are adding a String to a list that takes Menu.

Comment: @Pankaj Singhal thanks for your comment, All I need to print out the itemChosen from table Menu, by the way I choose Item by Item ID and I want to print out the values of this chosen Item like Nam, Price, type and etc

Comment: See @Daniel's answer. It points in the correct direction

Answer (score 1):

The type error is pretty clear to me:

`Menu.getAllRows(...)` returns `String`.
`listItem.add(...)` takes `Menu` as an argument.

A `String` is not a `Menu`. Therefore you have a type error.

That said: you have many, many other things wrong with this code. Names that defy standard Java naming conventions, methods that don't do anything useful (why does `getAllRows` take `Object` as an argument but just cast it to a `String` to return it?), using `float` to store a currency value, and probably more.

Comment: you have an eagle's eye

Comment: Actually, not that much of an eagle eye. I saw the question, said "no way I'm reading through all that code", and hit Ctrl-F to search in the page, and typed "add(", which took me exactly to the line of code with the error.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden thanks a lot I am trying to figure it

Comment: @DanielPryden haha. Smart thing, you did.

Comment: @DanielPryden thanks a lot for your help I tried to change the return value instead of String to menu but I find underlined error with ItemChosen that said String can not be converted to Menu, Could you help me to solve this please I just need to return the value I chosen from Menu Table

Comment: Well, what are you returning, an item that was chosen or a `Menu`? It sounds like you're asking me to debug your program for you, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow. But you might find this essay useful: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @DanielPryden am returning now in method getAllRows a Menu which itemChosen a type of String so I think that I want to Convert this type of String to a Menu I tried to cast this String to Menu but it dosen't work also